# how can i output 200khz in the esp2866

Tags: c++, c, arduino

in a project I'm working on I had issues with generating a transmitter signal which shall have 200khz and 50% duty cycle, The problem is in accessing the internal register of the esp using "PWM.h" library from the SDK, Is it possible to do it just from the arduino ide or it shall be done using sdk if So please provide a code snippet or a similar example. Thank You

Comment: Did you call `pwm_set_period(5);` and get an error? The doc says "_Do not set the period below 20µs_"

Comment: The SDK's PWM library from Espressif is not all that good. There is a replacement library here: https://github.com/StefanBruens/ESP8266_new_pwm that may do what you want.